# D3 tree with boxes

Tags: d3.js

With my limited D3 knowledge, I've combined some tree layout examples to make a collapsible tree with branch labels. Here is a functional extract:

```js
var root = {
    children:[
        {
            title:"Node title",
            children:[
                {
                    type:"end",
                    items:[],
                    optionTitle:"Branch 1"
                },
                {
                    type:"end",
                    items:[],
                    optionTitle:"Branch 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

var maxLabelLength = 23;
var i = 0;
var duration = 750;

// Define the root
root.x0 = viewerHeight / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

var viewerWidth = 800;
var viewerHeight = 300;

var tree = d3.layout.tree();

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) {
        return [d.y, d.x];
    });

function visit(parent, visitFn, childrenFn) {
    if (!parent) return;

    visitFn(parent);

    var children = childrenFn(parent);
    if (children) {
        var count = children.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            visit(children[i], visitFn, childrenFn);
        }
    }
}

var baseSvg = d3.select('.tree').append("svg")
    .attr("width", viewerWidth)
    .attr("height", viewerHeight)
    .attr("class", "tree-container");


// Helper functions for collapsing and expanding nodes.
function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

function centerNode(source) {
    var scale = 1;
    var x = 20;
    var y = -source.x0;
    y = y * scale + viewerHeight / 2;
    d3.select('g').transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
}

function toggleChildren(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else if (d._children) {
        expand(d);
    }
    return d;
}

function expand(d) {
    if (d._children) {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
        if (d.children.length == 1) {
            expand(d.children[0])
        }
    }
}

function click(d) {
    if (d._children) {
        if (d.type!='end') {
            expandCollapse(d);
        }
    } else {
        expandCollapse(d);
    }
}

function expandCollapse(d) {
    d = toggleChildren(d);
    update(d);
    centerNode(d);
}

function update(source) {
    var levelWidth = [1];
    var childCount = function(level, n) {

        if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
            if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

            levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
            n.children.forEach(function(d) {
                childCount(level + 1, d);
            });
        }
    };
    childCount(0, root);
    var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 25;
    tree = tree.size([newHeight, viewerWidth]);

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Set widths between levels based on maxLabelLength.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = (d.depth * (maxLabelLength * 8)); 

        if (d.x<root.x) {
            d.x -= (root.x-d.x)*3;
        } else if (d.x>root.x) {
            d.x += (d.x-root.x)*3;
        }
    });

    // Update the nodes…
    var node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on('click', click);

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr('class', 'nodeCircle');
        
    // Change the circle fill depending on whether it has children and is collapsed
    node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
        .attr("r", 6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return getNodeFill(d);
        });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
        })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr('class', 'nodeText')
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.title;
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);


    // Update the text to reflect whether node has children or not.
    node.select('text')
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            if (d.type!='end') {
                return d.title
            } else {
                return 'End node'
            }
        });

    // Transition nodes to their new position.
    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

    // Fade the text in
    nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 0);

    nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d) {
            return d.target.id;
        });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {
                x: source.x0,
                y: source.y0
            };
            return diagonal({
                source: o,
                target: o
            });
        });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {
                x: source.x,
                y: source.y
            };
            return diagonal({
                source: o,
                target: o
            });
        })
        .remove();

    // Update the link text
    var linktext = svgGroup.selectAll("g.link")
        .data(links, function (d) {
            return d.target.id;
        });

    linktext.enter()
        .insert("g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.target.optionTitle;
        });

    // Transition link text to their new positions

    linktext.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + ((d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2) + "," + ((d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2) + ")";
        })

    //Transition exiting link text to the parent's new position.
    linktext.exit().transition().remove();


    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });


}

var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g");

// Layout the tree initially and center on the root node.
update(root);
centerNode(root);

svgGroup
    .append('defs')
    .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', function(d,i){
        return 'pic_plus';
    })
    .attr('height',60)
    .attr('width',60)
    .attr('x',0)
    .attr('y',0)
    .append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href',function(d,i){
        return 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eq-static/app/images/common/plus.png';
    })
    .attr('height',12)
    .attr('width',12)
    .attr('x',0)
    .attr('y',0);

function getNodeFill(d) {
    if (isFinal(d)) {
        return '#0f0';
    } else if (d._children || (!d._children&&!d.children)) {
        return 'url(#pic_plus)'
    } else {
        return '#fff'
    }
}

function isFinal(node) {
    return node.type=='end';
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.tree-custom,
.tree {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.holder {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.node {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

path.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    fill: #666;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <div class="tree"></div>
  <script src="code.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my code, the nodes are circles with the node labels next to them:

[image: Expanded tree example]

When I collapse a node, a `plus`sign shows up.

[image: Collapsed tree example]

Now I'm trying to put the node labels in boxes as it's shown in this [example code](https://bl.ocks.org/swayvil/b86f8d4941bdfcbfff8f69619cd2f460).

[image: Boxed labels]

I know I have to change the `circles` by `foreignObjects`as in the example code but when I do it, paths aren't adjusted to the boxes.

How could I change the `circles` by `foreignObjects` and maintain the same functionality expand/collapse/plus?

Comment: Could you edit your code to include what you have done so far to change `circles` to `foreignObjects` so we can see where you're stuck?

Comment: Sure, please see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a95pjnoL/17/. Only take into consideration the blue box labelled `Node title` as this code is just a fast proof of concept prototype.

Comment: where do you want the plus to go?

Comment: In the same box underneath the node label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes that you need to make to your current layout are:

- move the blue boxes to be vertically aligned with the circles and with the right edge adjacent to the left side of each circle;
- alter the paths to terminate at the left side of each blue box

The first can be done using a transform to alter the position of the blue boxes, and the second by altering the coordinates for the target point of each line.

Looking at the sample you linked to, there are `rect` elements behind the `foreignObject` elements that provide the colour, and the `foreignObject` is offset from the position of the `rect` elements. I have taken the liberty of adding the `rect` elements to your code and grouping the `rect` and `foreignObject` elements together so they can be moved in a single transform:

```
var rectGrpEnter = nodeEnter.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node-rect-text-grp');

rectGrpEnter.append('rect')
    .attr('rx', 6)
    .attr('ry', 6)
    .attr('width', rectNode.width)
    .attr('height', rectNode.height)
    .attr('class', 'node-rect');

rectGrpEnter.append('foreignObject')
    .attr('x', rectNode.textMargin)
    .attr('y', rectNode.textMargin)
    .attr('width', function() {
        return (rectNode.width - rectNode.textMargin * 2) < 0 ? 0 :
            (rectNode.width - rectNode.textMargin * 2)
    })
    .attr('height', function() {
        return (rectNode.height - rectNode.textMargin * 2) < 0 ? 0 :
            (rectNode.height - rectNode.textMargin * 2)
    })
    .append('xhtml').html(function(d) {
        return '<div style="width: ' +
            (rectNode.width - rectNode.textMargin * 2) + 'px; height: ' +
            (rectNode.height - rectNode.textMargin * 2) + 'px;" class="node-text wordwrap">' +
            '<b>' + d.title + '</b>' +
            '</div>';
    });
```

If you look at the tree this produces, the `rect`/`foreignObject` group needs to be translated the length of the `rect` element + the `circle` radius along the x axis, and by half the height of the `rect` element along the y axis. So, first let's add a variable to represent the circle radius and replace the hard-coded number with that variable:

```
var circleRadius = 6;

// a bit further on
node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
    .attr("r", circleRadius)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return getNodeFill(d);
    });
```

Now write the transform:

```
var rectGrpEnter = nodeEnter.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node-rect-text-grp')
    .attr('transform', 'translate('
    + -(rectNode.width + circleRadius) + ','  // note the transform is negative
    + -(rectNode.height/2) + ')' );
```

Check the resulting tree:

```js
var rectNode = {
  width: 120,
  height: 45,
  textMargin: 5
};

var root = {
  slideId: 100,
  children: [{
    title: "Node title",
    children: [{
        type: "end",
        items: [],
        optionTitle: "Branch 1"
      },
      {
        type: "end",
        items: [],
        optionTitle: "Branch 2"
      }
    ]
  }]
}

var maxLabelLength = 23;
var i = 0;
var duration = 750;

// Define the root
root.x0 = viewerHeight / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

var viewerWidth = 800;
var viewerHeight = 300;

var tree = d3.layout.tree();

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

function visit(parent, visitFn, childrenFn) {
  if (!parent) return;

  visitFn(parent);

  var children = childrenFn(parent);
  if (children) {
    var count = children.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      visit(children[i], visitFn, childrenFn);
    }
  }
}

var baseSvg = d3.select('.tree').append("svg")
  .attr("width", viewerWidth)
  .attr("height", viewerHeight)
  .attr("class", "tree-container");

// Helper functions for collapsing and expanding nodes.
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}

function centerNode(source) {
  var scale = 1;
  var x = 20;
  var y = -source.x0;
  y = y * scale + viewerHeight / 2;
  d3.select('g').transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
}

function toggleChildren(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else if (d._children) {
    expand(d);
  }
  return d;
}

function expand(d) {
  if (d._children) {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
    if (d.children.length == 1) {
      expand(d.children[0])
    }
  }
}

function click(d) {
  if (d._children) {
    if (d.type != 'end') {
      expandCollapse(d);
    }
  } else {
    expandCollapse(d);
  }
}

function expandCollapse(d) {
  d = toggleChildren(d);
  update(d);
  centerNode(d);
}

function update(source) {
  var levelWidth = [1];
  var childCount = function(level, n) {

    if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
      if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

      levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
      n.children.forEach(function(d) {
        childCount(level + 1, d);
      });
    }
  };
  childCount(0, root);
  var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 25;
  var circleRadius = 6;

  tree = tree.size([newHeight, viewerWidth]);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Set widths between levels based on maxLabelLength.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = (d.depth * (maxLabelLength * 8));

    if (d.x < root.x) {
      d.x -= (root.x - d.x) * 3;
    } else if (d.x > root.x) {
      d.x += (d.x - root.x) * 3;
    }
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  var rectGrpEnter = nodeEnter.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node-rect-text-grp')
    .attr('transform', 'translate('
    + -(rectNode.width + circleRadius) + ','  // note the transform is negative
    + -(rectNode.height/2) + ')' );

  rectGrpEnter.append('rect')
    .attr('rx', 6)
    .attr('ry', 6)
    .attr('width', rectNode.width)
    .attr('height', rectNode.height)
    .attr('class', 'node-rect');

  rectGrpEnter.append('foreignObject')
    .attr('x', rectNode.textMargin)
    .attr('y', rectNode.textMargin)
    .attr('width', function() {
      return (rectNode.width - rectNode.textMargin * 2) < 0 ? 0 :
        (rectNode.width - rectNode.textMargin * 2)
    })
    .attr('height', function() {
      return (rectNode.height - rectNode.textMargin * 2) < 0 ? 0 :
        (rectNode.height - rectNode.textMargin * 2)
    })
    .append('xhtml').html(function(d) {
      return '<div style="width: ' +
        (rectNode.width - rectNode.textMargin * 2) + 'px; height: ' +
        (rectNode.height - rectNode.textMargin * 2) + 'px;" class="node-text wordwrap">' +
        '<b>' + d.title + '</b>' +
        '</div>';
    });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr('class', 'nodeCircle');

  // Change the circle fill depending on whether it has children and is collapsed
  node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
    .attr("r", circleRadius)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return getNodeFill(d);
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr('class', 'nodeText')
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.title;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 0);


  // Update the text to reflect whether node has children or not.
  node.select('text')
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      if (d.type != 'end') {
        return d.title
      } else {
        return 'End node'
      }
    });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  // Fade the text in
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 0);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Update the link text
  var linktext = svgGroup.selectAll("g.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  linktext.enter()
    .insert("g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.target.optionTitle;
    });

  // Transition link text to their new positions

  linktext.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + ((d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2) + "," + ((d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2) + ")";
    })

  //Transition exiting link text to the parent's new position.
  linktext.exit().transition().remove();


  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });


}

var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g");

// Layout the tree initially and center on the root node.
update(root);
centerNode(root);

svgGroup
  .append('defs')
  .append('pattern')
  .attr('id', function(d, i) {
    return 'pic_plus';
  })
  .attr('height', 60)
  .attr('width', 60)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .append('image')
  .attr('xlink:href', function(d, i) {
    return 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eq-static/app/images/common/plus.png';
  })
  .attr('height', 12)
  .attr('width', 12)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0);

function getNodeFill(d) {
  if (isFinal(d)) {
    return '#0f0';
  } else if (d._children || (!d._children && !d.children)) {
    return 'url(#pic_plus)'
  } else {
    return '#fff'
  }
}

function isFinal(node) {
  return node.type == 'end';
}

function isCollapsed(node) {
  return d._children || (!d._children && !d.children);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tree-custom,
.tree {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.holder {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  fill: #666;
}

.node-rect {
  fill: #00f;
}

.node-text {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tree"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The next task is to alter the links to terminate at the edge of the `rect` boxes. If you check the code that covers the link positions and transitions, the `enter` and `exit` selections both use the position of the `source` node. The code we are interested in is this:

```
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);
```

where the diagonal function is

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });
```

`d3.svg.diagonal()` takes an object of the form

```
{ source: { x: 10, y: 10 }, target: { x: 20, y: 50 } }
```

and if you look at each item in the `tree.links` array, you'll see it is in the form

```
{ source: { /* source node coordinates */ }, target: { /* target node coords */ }
```

so to alter the position of the link target, we need to create a new object with the `target` coordinates altered. Once again, the x axis alteration should be `-(rectNode.width + circleRadius)`; the y axis is OK. Note that the `diagonal` function switches over the `x` and `y` values, though, so we need to alter the target's `y` value, not the `x` value. Thus, we have:

```
  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return diagonal({
        source: d.source,  // this is the same
        target: { x: d.target.x, y: d.target.y - (rectNode.width + circleRadius) } 
      });
    });
```

Add that to our code:

```js
var rectNode = {
  width: 120,
  height: 45,
  textMargin: 5
};

var root = {
  slideId: 100,
  children: [{
    title: "Node title",
    children: [{
        type: "end",
        items: [],
        optionTitle: "Branch 1"
      },
      {
        type: "end",
        items: [],
        optionTitle: "Branch 2"
      }
    ]
  }]
}

var maxLabelLength = 23;
var i = 0;
var duration = 750;

// Define the root
root.x0 = viewerHeight / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

var viewerWidth = 800;
var viewerHeight = 300;

var tree = d3.layout.tree();

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

function visit(parent, visitFn, childrenFn) {
  if (!parent) return;

  visitFn(parent);

  var children = childrenFn(parent);
  if (children) {
    var count = children.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      visit(children[i], visitFn, childrenFn);
    }
  }
}

var baseSvg = d3.select('.tree').append("svg")
  .attr("width", viewerWidth)
  .attr("height", viewerHeight)
  .attr("class", "tree-container");

// Helper functions for collapsing and expanding nodes.
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}

function centerNode(source) {
  var scale = 1;
  var x = 20;
  var y = -source.x0;
  y = y * scale + viewerHeight / 2;
  d3.select('g').transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
}

function toggleChildren(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else if (d._children) {
    expand(d);
  }
  return d;
}

function expand(d) {
  if (d._children) {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
    if (d.children.length == 1) {
      expand(d.children[0])
    }
  }
}

function click(d) {
  if (d._children) {
    if (d.type != 'end') {
      expandCollapse(d);
    }
  } else {
    expandCollapse(d);
  }
}

function expandCollapse(d) {
  d = toggleChildren(d);
  update(d);
  centerNode(d);
}

function update(source) {
  var levelWidth = [1];
  var childCount = function(level, n) {

    if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
      if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

      levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
      n.children.forEach(function(d) {
        childCount(level + 1, d);
      });
    }
  };
  childCount(0, root);
  var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 25;
  var circleRadius = 6;

  tree = tree.size([newHeight, viewerWidth]);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Set widths between levels based on maxLabelLength.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = (d.depth * (maxLabelLength * 8));

    if (d.x < root.x) {
      d.x -= (root.x - d.x) * 3;
    } else if (d.x > root.x) {
      d.x += (d.x - root.x) * 3;
    }
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  var rectGrpEnter = nodeEnter.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node-rect-text-grp')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' +
      -(rectNode.width + circleRadius) + ',' // note the transform is negative
      +
      -(rectNode.height / 2) + ')');

  rectGrpEnter.append('rect')
    .attr('rx', 6)
    .attr('ry', 6)
    .attr('width', rectNode.width)
    .attr('height', rectNode.height)
    .attr('class', 'node-rect');

  rectGrpEnter.append('foreignObject')
    .attr('x', rectNode.textMargin)
    .attr('y', rectNode.textMargin)
    .attr('width', function() {
      return (rectNode.width - rectNode.textMargin * 2) < 0 ? 0 :
        (rectNode.width - rectNode.textMargin * 2)
    })
    .attr('height', function() {
      return (rectNode.height - rectNode.textMargin * 2) < 0 ? 0 :
        (rectNode.height - rectNode.textMargin * 2)
    })
    .append('xhtml').html(function(d) {
      return '<div style="width: ' +
        (rectNode.width - rectNode.textMargin * 2) + 'px; height: ' +
        (rectNode.height - rectNode.textMargin * 2) + 'px;" class="node-text wordwrap">' +
        '<b>' + d.title + '</b>' +
        '</div>';
    });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr('class', 'nodeCircle');

  // Change the circle fill depending on whether it has children and is collapsed
  node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
    .attr("r", circleRadius)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return getNodeFill(d);
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr('class', 'nodeText')
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.title;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 0);


  // Update the text to reflect whether node has children or not.
  node.select('text')
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      if (d.type != 'end') {
        return d.title
      } else {
        return 'End node'
      }
    });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  // Fade the text in
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 0);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return diagonal({
        source: d.source,
        target: { x: d.target.x, y: d.target.y - (rectNode.width + circleRadius) }
      });
    });


  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Update the link text
  var linktext = svgGroup.selectAll("g.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  linktext.enter()
    .insert("g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.target.optionTitle;
    });

  // Transition link text to their new positions

  linktext.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + ((d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2) + "," + ((d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2) + ")";
    })

  //Transition exiting link text to the parent's new position.
  linktext.exit().transition().remove();


  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });


}

var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g");

// Layout the tree initially and center on the root node.
update(root);
centerNode(root);

svgGroup
  .append('defs')
  .append('pattern')
  .attr('id', function(d, i) {
    return 'pic_plus';
  })
  .attr('height', 60)
  .attr('width', 60)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .append('image')
  .attr('xlink:href', function(d, i) {
    return 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eq-static/app/images/common/plus.png';
  })
  .attr('height', 12)
  .attr('width', 12)
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0);

function getNodeFill(d) {
  if (isFinal(d)) {
    return '#0f0';
  } else if (d._children || (!d._children && !d.children)) {
    return 'url(#pic_plus)'
  } else {
    return '#fff'
  }
}

function isFinal(node) {
  return node.type == 'end';
}

function isCollapsed(node) {
  return d._children || (!d._children && !d.children);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tree-custom,
.tree {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.holder {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  fill: #666;
}

.node-rect {
  fill: #00f;
}

.node-text {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tree"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can check that the links are terminating in the correct place by removing the fill on the `rect` elements.

There are now a number of other fixes to be made, but that should have proved your proof of concept; if you are unclear about any parts of the new code, please just ask.

Comment: Awesome! That is just what I need. Thanks specially for your detailed explanation.